# Android uncheck select all checkbox on Recycler item uncheck

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

I have recycler view items with Checkbox component and implemented common "Check All" button. When I "uncheck" the button in list item, I want to "uncheck" common "Select All" Checkbox outside the recycler view.

I having issue in accessing the common "Select All" Checkbox in Adapter.

In my adapter class added below code,

```
private class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public CheckBox commonCheckbox, itemCheckbox;
    public UserViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        itemCheckbox=view.findViewById(R.id.itemcheckbox);
        title=view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        commonCheckbox = view.findViewById(R.id.commoncheckbox);
    }
}
```

In onBindViewHolder, I implemented the following checked listener,

```
userViewHolder.itemCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                userViewHolder.commonCheckbox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

But, commonCheckbox showing null pointer exception. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in UserViewholder contain commonCheckbox and itemCheckbox but in bindview you access to checkBox? where does that checkbox came from?

Comment: Better you hold checkbox value as property of list of RecyclerView. Then set value as per that in `BindViewHolder` and change list's value on `setOnCheckedChangeListener` of checkbox.

Comment: @SopheakSok: now updated the code. same issue

Answer (score 0):

The view holder would be holding the layout of the recycled views items yes, so the Id wouldn’t not show as “incorrect” as you have an ID with that name, but the view that it is looking for the ID In is not the same view that the common check box is in, that would be why it is returning null.

I believe the easiest solution would be to pass in a Listener to the viewholder and call a method from the listener to uncheck the common check box when your onCheckChanged listener is called

Comment: can u share any example snippet??

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I achieved using the interface approach.
Adapter class code below,

```
//Interface class
public interface OnDataChangeListener{
    public void onDataChanged(int size);
}
//Listener discussion
OnDataChangeListener mOnDataChangeListener;
public void setOnDataChangeListener(OnDataChangeListener onDataChangeListener){
    mOnDataChangeListener = onDataChangeListener;
}
//Set listener
userViewHolder.itemCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                mOnDataChangeListener.onDataChanged(homeworkdate.size());
            }
        }
    });
```

In activity class code below,

```
classAdapter.setOnDataChangeListener(new classAdapter.OnDataChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChanged(int size) {
                            commonCheckbox.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    });
```